# Configure larger limit of columns on Format module

Tags: format, ocaml

#### The Format module

The [Format](https://github.com/lucasaiu/ocaml/blob/master/stdlib/format.mli) module is used to model and combine pretty printers with a syntactic extension that allows typed formats and it helps a lot when you are writing something like a code generator or a data structure printer.

#### The problem

However, there is a limit of [78 columns](https://github.com/lucasaiu/ocaml/blob/master/stdlib/format.ml#L124) that is initialized on the margin of the formatter and will pull to the left anything that takes more than this limit.

I'm printing a lighter version of a `Yojson.Basic.json` program using the `Format` module, but when the input is too large, the output is collapsed, and that is not really "prettily".

#### Preview

- Here is how it is is formatted when it is short:
  [image: Correct]
- Here is how it is formatted when the indentation becomes too large
  [image: Wrong]

I've been trying to exceed and configure this limit to 120 columns, but didn't have any success.

#### What have I tried?

- Using `Format.pp_set_margin ppf 120` to reconfigure
- Using `Format.pp_set_max_indent` to a larger value

But they doesn't seem to have any effect and there is no documentation easily available about this limit. I've discovered it only by reading the source code.

#### What am I doing?

```
let string_of_cst program =
  let ppf = Format.str_formatter in
  (* I've enabled colors. *)
  Format.pp_set_tags ppf colors;
  Format.pp_set_formatter_tag_functions ppf with_colors;
  (* [print_json] is my printer. *)
  print_json ppf program;
  (* Get string out of printer. *)
  Format.flush_str_formatter ()
```

How can I configure a larger limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the values for `margin` and `max_indent` are implicitly constrained to the cone `1 < max_indent < margin` and the function `set_max_indent` silently fails and does nothing if this constraint is not respected.

To avoid this issue, in OCaml ≥4.08, it would be possible to use the new `set_geometry` function that requires to set both value simultaneously and fails with an exception if the required `max_indent` is greater than the margin.

Otherwise, you should always set both values at the same time, and always in the order
`margin` first, and `max_indent` second. If you don't know which value to chose for `max_indent`,  `margin - 10` is generally an alright choice.